# Error in CDbException when hosting yii app on godaddy

Tags: php, yii

I having one yii app hosted on godaddy windows hosting server,

All db config is ok but i am facing one error as **CDbException

CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection.**

```
'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db_name',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'myusername',
        'password' => 'mypassword',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_'
    ),
```

all host name dbname username and pasword is correct then also i am facing with this error.

If someone have all ready solved this problem of hosting yii app on godaddy windows server please help me....

Thank you in advance..

Comment: this is a too little information to help here I think. from the yii settings it seems to be OK

Comment: Yes, there is no any error in yii code, but the server is not connecting to the database, i don't know what is the problem in server configuration, do you know the exact problem why it is happening?

Comment: did you check with core php code to confirm db is connecting with your username and password?

Comment: kindly upload a php file dbconnect.php with normal php+mysql connection string. Execute the .php file and debug. Let us know what are the errors you are getting

Comment: no i didn't check the core php code yet, but as the sample provided by them i am using same host name as they suggested, also i tried as localhost, but the error is still there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the error message continue with "could not find driver?" Godaddy has PHP's PDO extension disabled on its Windows boxes (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18511138/3012385)). Fastest solution were to change your hosting plan to Linux.